# How to set a bitmap from resource

Tags: android, bitmap

This seems simple, I am trying to set a bitmap image but from the resources, I have within the application in the drawable folder.

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.id.image);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 806, accepted):

Assuming you are calling this in an Activity class

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

The first parameter, Resources, is required. It is normally obtainable in any Context (and subclasses like Activity).

Comment: I am getting null value of bitmap ,can u say me why i am getting null

Comment: yes i'm getting the same issue, null value of the bitmap.

Comment: I got the issue. I was trying to convert vector drawable into bitmap. So here is the cod to convert vector drawable into bitmap.

Comment: If **not** calling from an Activity class (e.g., if called from a data class) you could try:  val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.your_image) <—Kotlin

Comment: I was gettin null value of Bitmap because I was using a vector resource (it you use a `.png` for example it works)

Answer (score 40):

Try this

This is from sdcard

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test2.png");
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

This is from resources

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 9):

If the resource is showing and is a view, you can also capture it. Like a screenshot:

```
View rootView = ((View) findViewById(R.id.yourView)).getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rootView.layout(0, 0, rootView.getWidth(), rootView.getHeight());
rootView.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());

rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

This actually grabs the whole layout but you can alter as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

If you have declare a bitmap object and you want to display it or store this bitmap object. but first you have to assign any image , and you may use the button click event, this code will only demonstrate that how to store the drawable image in bitmap Object.

```
Bitmap contact_pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                           v.getContext().getResources(),
                           R.drawable.android_logo
                     );
```

Now you can use this bitmap object, whether you want to store it, or to use it in google maps while drawing a pic on fixed latitude and longitude, or to use some where else

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.id.image);
```

with

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YourImageName);
```

I mean to say just change null value with getResources() If you use this code in any button or Image view click event just append getApplicationContext() before getResources()..

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you can get Image Bitmap. Just pass image url

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
 }
```