# Android - Setting colour to image

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm getting stuck at a certain part of my app.

In my app, I have a few icons. The icons are completely white with transparent backgrounds. Is it possible for the user to set the colour of the icons without messing up the transparency? I tried searching a lot, but couldn't come up with anything. Could someone help me out?

Also would it be possible for the user to set custom icons from any folder as per their choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You have to create bitmap from resource [How to set a bitmap from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955268/how-to-set-a-bitmap-from-resource), then search bitmap for white pixels and change them to desired color (pix - by pix), then just set result bitmap as button or other layout element bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it and report. :)