# How to set image on canvas from resource class

Tags: android

I try to set bitmap image from drawable that i declare on resource.java. When i click next button,it will show another image that i can draw. Is this right code to call it?

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Resource.capitalStoke[DrawingActivity.this.position]);
```

or anymore to add?

this is my resource.java:

```
public class Resource {

    public static String DRAWING_ALPHABET;
    public static Integer[] capitalStoke;
    Integer[] alphabetCapital;
    Integer[] alphabetSound;
    Integer[] alphabetImage;

    static {
        DRAWING_ALPHABET = "alphabet";
        capitalStoke = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.capital_letters_stroke_01),
                                     Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.capital_letters_stroke_02),
                                     Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.capital_letters_stroke_03),};
        }
```

is that possible to retrieve image from here using bitmapfactory?if possible,how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's right following to this [How to set a bitmap from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955268/how-to-set-a-bitmap-from-resource).

In my opinion better idea is to use it in common way - just constants like `R.id.drawable_1;`. You can always store followings ids in array or list to iterate.